# How to call the correct view method in Django?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I have a project with these files and folders:

```
...
old
project
new
common
manage.py
...
```

I access the "old" using http://127.0.0.1:8000/old
and there are views, form urls, etc files inside this folder. all works fine.

I have similar files inside "new" folder  as well. It also runs well: http://127.0.0.1:8000/old

However I run into problems when I have a method inside view ("method1") and I declare it inside urls. However it searches for the method1 inside folder "old" not in "new".

```
$.post('{% url "method1" %}
```

inside urls I have

```
path('method/', views.method1, name='method1'),
```

I have no idea why this js searches for method1 inside "old". When I declare method1 inside old folder, it works fine.

What am I missing here?

**Update**

It works without js, this method is fine, but inside js code it fails
I put the js code here:

```
{% block domready %}
  $('a.cost').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('{% url "method1" %}',
      {
        action: $(this).data('action')
      },
      function(data){
        //...
      }
    );
  });
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: what is `ROOT_URLCONF` in your settings.py? And where is settings.py? Which of these folders are apps and which is the main project folder containing **wsgi.py** and **settings.py**?

Comment: Also it's not clear what you mean by "it searches for method1 inside "old"", do you see an error? If so, please share the full error trace. Maybe, reading [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/) again could help you understand better. "js searches for method1" does not make sense.

Comment: It tells: Reverse for 'method1/' not found. 'method1/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: 'method1/'??? It should say 'method1' according to what you show above. Where does the slash come from?

Comment: there is no slash sorry.

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls' and os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

This drives me crazy))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have problem in your other 'urls.py' it is probably located in the 'project' directory.

You need to have both your apps in the main urlpatterns of your project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('old/', include('old.urls')),
    path('new/', include('new.urls'))
]
```

If you are trying to use different folders to store different things then sorry, but default django router works with applications, so you have one directory per application.
So for 'old' application you do everything inside 'old' folder and if you want to make another application - you need to make one.

If you add a `namespace` to your urls for the app `new`, then you need to prefix all the names when you reverse the url:

```
{% url "new:method1" %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have both, but like this: urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('old/', include('old.urls')),
    path('new/', include('new.urls', namespace='new')),
]

Comment: Since you're name spacing your urls for the `new` app, the pattern name is "new:method1"